# coffee script switch without break

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is it possible to use switch in coffeescript without break?

```
switch code                      switch (code) {
    when 37 then                     case 37: break;
    when 38 then           ->        case 38: break;
    when 39 then                     case 39: break;
    when 40                          case 40:
        ...                              ...
```

I thought this will work but failed:

```
switch code
    when 37 then continue
    when 38 then continue  ->    not valid
    when 39 then continue
    when 40
        ...
```

Comment: you don't want a coffee break? (sorry couldn't resist)

Comment: AFAIK, no. Perhaps more elaboration on what you're trying to do would help us come up with an appropriate alternative.

Comment: I am completely sure that switch with hardcoded break is bad. I Will check source of coffee compiler now

Comment: I would imagine this is to stop fall fall-through.

Comment: Fall-through in C-style switch/case has long been considered an anti-pattern by most, and leads to a lot of bugs when the `break`s are forgotten.  If you can tell us why you think fall-through is necessary for your situation, I'm sure someone will tell you how to do it in CoffeeScript style.

Comment: @AaronDufour is right. What case do you find necessary to need a fall-through switch?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Not really. From [the docs](http://coffeescript.org/#switch):

> Switch statements in JavaScript are a bit awkward. You need to remember to break at the end of every case statement to avoid accidentally falling through to the default case. CoffeeScript prevents accidental fall-through, and can convert the switch into a returnable, assignable expression. The format is: switch condition,  when clauses, else the default case.

What you can do, though, is specify several values in a `case`, if they are to be treated equally:

```
switch day
  when "Mon" then go work
  when "Tue" then go relax
  when "Thu" then go iceFishing
  when "Fri", "Sat"
    if day is bingoDay
      go bingo
      go dancing
  when "Sun" then go church
  else go work
```

Comment: when "go work" and "go relax" and "go iceFishing" and "go church" is the same code: this is bad way

Comment: I'm not commenting on whether this is good or bad -- you asked a question about CoffeeScript, and this is what CoffeeScript's author thinks. He is not alone in thinking C-style `switch`-statements are bad. That said, what's so bad about `when "Mon", "Tue", "Thu", "Sun"` though?

Comment: switch statements in Javascript are the same as everywhere else : on all languages (as far as I know) you have to break at the end of the case if you don't want the next one to be evaluated. I guess this is on purpose to have a control over it.

Comment: @challet - No. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression

Comment: @ciastek thank you're right. but my main point was that "break" can be useful.

Answer (score 12):

You can use line continuation to help with this.  For example:

```
name = 'Jill'

switch name
  when 'Jill', \
       'Joan', \
       'Jess', \
       'Jean'
    $('#display').text 'Hi!'
  else
    $('#display').text 'Bye!'
```

[Check it out in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/icylace/9vrZ7/1/)

Comment: seems like a parser fail, should auto allow continuation of lines that end with a , or am I projecting? (commenting on the \ continuations all over code)

Answer (score 4):

It's totally possible, just use a classic javascript and pass it through with backtics

```
`
switch (code) {
    case 37:
    case 38:
    case 39:
    case 40:
        // do the work of all four
    default:
        //default
}
`
```

Answer (score 2):

Old question already, but if you place the commas on the next line, it works as expected, without the backslash line continuation showed by @Ron Martinez

```
switch code
  when 37
     , 38
     , 39
     , 40
    console.log "Some Number"
  else
    console.log "Default"
```

Which will compile to:

```
switch (code) {
  case 37:
  case 38:
  case 39:
  case 40:
    return console.log("Some Number");
  default:
    return console.log("Default");
}
```